# python id() function implementation

Tags: python-3.x, built-in

How are python built-in functions are implemented? Some of them like `issubclass` are wrappers around object methods.

About id() [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) says that:

For CPython, id(x) is the memory address where x is stored.

When talking about id(), [other places](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) in documentation do not say anything more!

So how has id() been implemented? I think it doesn't have to do with any methods of the object in Cpython API. Just to have them, I used `dir(x)`:

```
foo = [1,2,3]
dir(foo)

>> ['__add__',
 '__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__iadd__',
 '__imul__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__reversed__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

Comment: There are multiple implementations of python. In cpython, all objects have a standard header and the id is the memory address of that header. References to objects are C pointers to their object header (that same memory address that is the id). You can't use a dunder method to find an object because you need the object pointer to find the dunder methods.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney. But how id() has access to that C object header?! All it sees is a python object!

Comment: Actually, no. Python is compiled into byte code and that byte code is executed by C. When you call a function like `id`, that function can be more byte code, but it can also be a C function. Search for "builtin_id` in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c and you'll see the C implementation of `id(some_object)`. That's the code being run. It takes the  memory address of `some_object` converts it to a python integer (called "long" in the C code `PyLong_FromVoidPtr(v)`) and returns.

Comment: You can learn more about the C interface with https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html and especially https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html.

Comment: Why would you expect a dunder method to be involved? That would imply objects could choose to reimplement it differently. Are you trying to overload it?

Comment: *"I expect that id() should use one of the dunder methods or attributes"* Why do you expect this? You expect wrong, simply. Dunder methods are for behaviour that each class can define for itself; classes cannot (and should not be able to) change what `id` does on their instances.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes! That's what I wanted to do!

Comment: @kaya3 I think this is what you can do with many of other built-in functions. For example, print() and str() use __str__ and __repr__ dunder methods! and you can change their behavior **on your specific class** .  The same for type(), super(), dir(), issubclass(), isinstance(), next(),.... . They all internally use the class's dunder methods.

Comment: @EhsanSh: Yeah, overloading `id` is nonsensical. If it's the same object, then it's the same object; if not, it's not. Allowing you to overload `id` would allow two independent objects to claim to be the *same* object, which is nuts (e.g. it would make it possible for `if myobj is None:` to return `True`, even when `myobj` is a custom class, not `None`; `is` is an identity test after all, and `id(x) == id(y)` is equivalent to testing `x is y`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple implementations of python. In cpython, all objects have a standard header and the id is the memory address of that header. References to objects are C pointers to their object header (that same memory address that is the id). You can't use a dunder method to find an object because you need the object pointer to find the dunder methods.

Python is compiled into byte code and that byte code is executed by C. When you call a function like `id`, that function can be more byte code, but it can also be a C function. Search for "builtin_id" in `bltinmodule.c` and you'll see the C implementation of `id(some_object)`.

```
static PyObject *
builtin_id(PyModuleDef *self, PyObject *v)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=0aa640785f697f65 input=5a534136419631f4]*/
{
    PyObject *id = PyLong_FromVoidPtr(v);

    if (id && PySys_Audit("builtins.id", "O", id) < 0) {
        Py_DECREF(id);
        return NULL;
    }

    return id;
}
```

The `id` function is called with `PyObject *v`, a pointer to the object whose id should be taken. `PyObject` is the standard object header used by all python objects. It includes information needed to figure out what type the object *really* is. The `id` function turns the object pointer into a python integer with `PyLong_FromVoidPtr` (the name "long" for a python int is somewhat historical). That's the id you see at the python level.

You can get the [cpython source on github](https://github.com/python/cpython) and you can read up on C in the python docs at [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) and [Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html#python-c-api-reference-manual)