# how can we explain id() built-in function output structure?

Tags: python, variables, memory-management, built-in

```
a = 5
id(a)
```

As you know,output is;

```
1936111069616
```

I know that this is a memory address reference of "a" variable linked between variable name and object heap and stack memory on ram in decimal format but i haven't found anything about the detailed definition of this address. If we wanted to write a user-defined function for this, how would we implement? I wonder the address structure and how we know unique format. What is the meaning of length of 13 numbers?

I searched this a lot. I haven't found exact definition for 64 bit system.

Comment: You can't do this with a user-defined function, it's internal implementation data.

Comment: A large portion of Python interpreter and its standard library is written in C, as far as I know, memory management and direct memory access can be done in C using pointers. I am not very knowledgeable in C programming, but you can have a look.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python id() function implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69762731/python-id-function-implementation)

Comment: The definition of `id` doesn't specify a memory address, just an `int` that is unique to the argument over its lifetime. The fact that CPython uses a memory address is just an implementation detail.

Comment: "I know that this is a memory address of "a" variable in decimal format" no, it is not the "address of a variable". It *happens* to be the address of the PyObject header, but that is *an implementation detail*. All `id` guarantees is that it returns an integer that is *unique* for the lifetime of the object

Answer (score 1):

The documentation explains `id` as much as it can be explained:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is
> guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its
> lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same
> `id()` value.

That's it. It's an integer with no further semantics of its own. Anything further is something specific to a particular *implementaton* of Python. The reference implementation that many people think of *as* Python is CPython, in which case...

> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
> memory.

... the particular integer *is* an address. But that's not something you can rely on or use. In any case, the implementation has to provide the value, because the implementation is in charge of managing the object over the course of its lifetime.

Comment: so in essence, it is a "massive" list of values where the index is the memory integer and the `ID()` function is retrieving the `index`...

Comment: What is the exact structure of this address? Why  it contains number of 13 length? Is it possible increment or decrement of this address length?

Comment: it is just an integer. presumable the max integer length represents the amount of memory available.

Comment: I know that there is a meaning but i haven't found exact of it. https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiwt1iVUib9s2Uo5BeYmwkDFUh70fJPxX

Comment: Virtual memory has nothing to do with Python's data model. Python doesn't even have a concept of memory; for all you know, your Python implementation could be storing all objects on disk in a SQL database, not in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to the number, but as others have mentioned:

> It's an integer with no further semantics of its own

You could inspect where values are assigned by looking at the `delta-memory`:

```py
x = 1
y = 2

a = 10
b = 20


a100 = 10
a101 = 11

memory_x = id(x)
memory_y = id(y)

memory_a = id(a)
memory_b = id(b)

memory_a100 = id(a100)
memory_a101 = id(a101)

print(id(x), id(y))
print(id(memory_x), id(memory_y))

mem_gap = id(y)-id(x)
print(mem_gap)

mem_gap = id(b)-id(a)
print(mem_gap)

mem_gap = id(a101)-id(a100)
print(mem_gap)
```

which give this:

```
1436097446128 1436097446160
1436179060400 1436179058480
32
320
32
```

so there is a consistency between the memory space of adjacent (integer) values `32`, but it is not immediately intuitive.

And the memory space between the floats are larger before looking at other types. The links take one to the implementation of memory in CPython, so the answer is there or by inspection as per the above.

(ie. its not any more clear in the docs).

Comment: I believe that someone knows about virtual memory can explain exactly. It is about virtual memory.

Comment: @SerdarGundogdu , i would tend to agree. although it was not immediately obvious in the documents.  I would expect that one could infer or derive such (with effort)...

Comment: To the extent that the id *is* a virtual address, that's a question regarding your local operating system and/or architecture, not your Python implementation.